# Create a tar file in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

How do I create/write a TAR file in OCaml? I know there is the **ocaml_tar** module, but I couldn't find any examples on how to create/write a TAR file. How do I do it in OCaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Archive.create](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/blob/master/lib/tar_unix.mli#L65) to create an archive on a file descriptor (if you want to create a file, use [Unix.openfile](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALopenfile)), to read a file, you have [`with_next_file`](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/blob/master/lib/tar_unix.mli#L55)`fd f` where the callback `f` should use the [Header.t](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/blob/master/lib/tar.mli#L19) to know the length of the data to read.  If you just want to extract the content to files, just use [extract](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/blob/master/lib/tar_unix.mli#L62).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use the existing `tar` tool of Linux, or relevant tools in Windows. For example, `tar -zcvf data.tgz *.doc`

And you can use functions in the `Sys` library to create a system call to the tool `tar`.